# TypeError: Object of type Folder is not JSON serializable in Django Rest framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using a property decorator for a field and have put that field into the serializer meta class but keeps getting that error. I am not sure what is the issue.

My models:

```
class Example(models.Model):

    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name="example"
    )


@property
def example_packages(self):
    return self.package.all()



class Package(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey(
                                Example,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null= True,
                                related_name="package"
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True)
```

My serializers:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = ['id','creator','example_packages']
```

The error that I keep geeting is that example_packages is not **Json serializable**.

Comment: In the code above, the property isn't indented in a model.
To which model does it belong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ['id','name']

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    package = PackageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = ['id','creator','package']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the @property needs to be in 'Example'

```
class Example(models.Model):

    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name="example"
    )

    @property
    def example_packages(self):
        return self.package.all()



class Package(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey(
                            Example,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            null= True,
                            related_name="package"
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True)
```

The serializer should look like:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    example_packages = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = ['id','creator','example_packages']
```

Comment: If I do this as charfield , i get the results of list of querysets in exxample_packages which is not what i wanted

Comment: You will always receive a queryset with `self.package.all()`.
You can change the data in `example_packages` to anything you want

Comment: I want fields of example_packages. how to achieve?